# Why is the affine function $f(x) = a^T x + b$ log-concave on $\{x | a^Tx + b \gt 0\}$?

Tags: convex-optimization

Why is the affine function $f(x) = a^T x + b$ log-concave on $\{x | a^Tx + b \gt 0\}$?

I see that for it to be log-concave we must have: $$f(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) \ge f(x)^{\theta}f(y)^{1-\theta}$$
Therefore we must have $$a^T(\theta x + (1-\theta)y) + b \ge (a^Tx + b)^{\theta}(a^Ty + b)^{1-\theta}$$
Which expands to $$\theta a^T x + (1-\theta)a^Ty + b \ge (a^Tx + b)^{\theta}(a^Ty + b)^{1-\theta}$$

But I can't see how to show this inequality from here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't _have_ to prove log-concavity this way. Just take the logarithm of the function, and prove that's concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you are trying to prove follows by Young’s inequality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products), which states that if $u,v \geq 0$ and $p, q \geq 1$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} =1$, then
$$ uv \leq \frac{u^p}{p} + \frac{v^q}{q}.
$$
In your case, you can apply the inequality for
$u = (a^Tx + b)^{\theta},$
$v = (a^Ty + b)^{1-\theta}$,
$p = \frac{1}{\theta},$
and
$q = \frac{1}{1 - \theta}.$

Answer (score 0):

Proving $f(x) = a^Tx + b$ is log-concave is equivalent to proving $g(f(x)) = \log(a^Tx + b)$ is concave. Since $g(y) = \log(y)$ is concave on $y > 0$, and since composition with affine function preserves concavity, $g(f(x))$ is concave on $f(x) > 0$.